# Is possible to route only one /64 ipv6 subnet for LAN?

Tags: ipv6

I have one /64 ipv6 subnet provided from my ISP. At home, I have one router (cisco 2801) with one WAN port (ethernet) and one LAN port (invalid ipv4 network 192.168.22.X) doing NAT.
Is possible to use this only one /64 network for my LAN devices? If so, how?
I can't use one IP on each interface (WAN and LAN) since both are from same subnet /64. The only thing that I can imagine is split this /64 into two /65 subnetworks, but this goes against good pratice that network shouldn't be smaller than /64, right?

Answer (score 2):

If your ISP is only providing you with one /64 on your WAN interface then their setup is broken. You need a /64 for each network, so one is not enough for both LAN and WAN. They should be delegating a whole block of multiple /64s to you.

The only ways you could make this work is by doing proxy-ND or by bridging IPv6 between LAN and WAN, making it appear like it's one network so the single /64 would work. It's a nasty hack though, and your ISP should provide you with proper address blocks so you wouldn't have to do that...

Answer (score 0):

Possible, yes. Recommended, no.
Autoconfig depends on having a /64 block at the smallest in order to do EUI-64 addressing.

If you go smaller than that, you will have to address everything by hand (ie, statically)